# How do I give a user rwx permissions everywhere? (Linux)

Tags: linux

How do I give my main Linux user read, write and execute in every directory?
When I make a new file through my terminal it's automatically read-only for my main user.

My virtualbox crashed and had to be reset so I lost all my user settings.
I'm using Trisquel.

thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could show the command you use to create a file, and then show with `ls -l` on that file to show the permissions. Directories that you create should automatically be read/write/execute for you, and ordinary files should be read/write. This is the default on most Unix systems without changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have 2 problem statements.

The first one is about giving your main user account read/write/execute access to every directory.

A quick way to do that would be to add the account to sudoers

```
vi /etc/sudoers
```

and add the user

```
username ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

The second problem statement is that files your main user creates are read-only. You can change this default by using the umask command:

```
umask 044
```

This will effectively chmod every file you create as 622 or rw-r--r--.